# Symfony 4: MailerInterface Failed to authenticate on SMTP server

Tags: symfony, mailer, dsn

Using [basic Symfony 4.4 example](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/mailer.html) to use MailerInterface, I setup this MAILER_DSN in my `.env` file:

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://email@example.com:123456@smtp.example.com:587
```

or this one (no port):

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://email@example.com:123456@smtp.example.com
```

I get this error:

> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "email@example.com" using the following authenticators: LOGIN, PLAIN

My server requires STARTTLS on port 587, but I don't know how to specify this with this DSN format.

Comment: Unfortunately a [configuration reference like for Swiftmailer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html) does not exist yet. STARTLS should be automatically enabled as Symfony Mailer automatically detects it (as of Symfony 4.4+). You should be able to pass in additional options as url parameters like with Swiftmailer, but I am not sure which specific one you need for your use case.

Comment: Yes, the docs are not very specific on DSN format

Comment: try login or plain at the end with your specific data :  smtp://user:pass@host:port/?timeout=60&encryption=tls&auth_mode=login

Comment: From the code I could gather that options are passed to [`stream_context_create()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create), so you should be able to use any of the [SSL context options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php) there, which from a quick glance look similar to the ones from Swiftmailer.

Comment: Since you do have your own mailserver, can you access its logs and search for the authentication attempts? Maybe that will give you a better error message to see which option you have to change exactly.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked when specifying the port (587) in the DSN, the mailer component correctly identified and used STARTTLS. What might be tricky in your example is that you need to escape the `@` in `email@example.com` with `%40`, so your DSN would be like this:

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://email%40example.com:123456@smtp.example.com:587
```

Any special URI characters need to be escaped (like `urlencode` does, so `+`, `@`, `$`, `#`, `/`, `:`, `*`, `!`), maybe that was the reason why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case
mailer.yml

```
framework:
    mailer:
        dsn: 'smtp://%env(MAILER_USER)%:%env(resolve:MAILER_PASS)%@%env(MAILER_HOST)%?encryption=tls&auth_mode=plain'
```

.env

```
MAILER_USER=user@server
MAILER_PASS=password$
MAILER_HOST=mail.server:25
```

Answer (score 0):

If your mail server password contains a # then you should quote the environment string since everything after # will be taken as comment (starting in Laravel 5.8)